# Unterminated address regex - misapplying escape characters in bash sed script?

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

Just learning sed, and I feel like I'm getting close to doing what I want, just missing something obvious.

The objective is to take bunch of `<tr>...</tr>`s in an html table and appended it to the single table in another page. So I want to take the initial file, strip everything above the first time I use `<tr>` and everything from `</table>` on down, then insert it just above the `</table>` in the other file. So like below, except `<tr>` and `</tr>` are on their own lines, if it matters.

```
Input File:                           Target File:
<html><body>                          <html><body>
  <p>Whatever...</p>                    <p>Other whatever...</p>
  <table>                               <table>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>                   <thead>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>                     <tr><th>#</th></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>                   </thead>
   </table>                               <tbody>
  </body></html>                            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </body></html>
```

Becomes:

```
  Input file                          Target File:
  doesn't matter.                     <html><body>
                                        <p>Other whatever...</p>
                                        <table>
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr><th>#</th></tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>4</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>5</td></tr>
                                            <tr><td>6</td></tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </body></html>
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 is the first parameter and $2 is the second parameter being passed when calling the script. The variable filename will be used to refer to this.

input=$1
inserttarget=$2

sed -e '/\<\/thead\>,$input' $input
sed -e '/\<\/table\>,$input' $input
sed -n -i -e '\<\/tbody\>/r' $inserttarget -e 1x -e '2,${x;p}' -e '${x;p}' $input
```

Pretty sure it's pretty simple, just messing the expression up. Can anyone set me straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I cut the problem in two:
 1. Cut the rows from the input
 2. Paste those rows in the output file

1. `sed -n '\:<table>:,\:</table>:p' ${input} | sed -n '\:<tr>:p'`

This line will remove all lines containing `<tr>` in the block ranging from the first line matching `<table>` to the first line matching `</table>`. All those freshly cut lines are printed in the standard output.

2. `sed -i '\:</tbody>: {
   r /dev/stdin
   a </tbody>
   d}' ${inserttarget}`

This multi-line command will add the lines read from `stdin` *after* the line matching `</tbody>`. Then we move the `</tbody>` by appending it *after* the new lines and removing the old one.

Another trick used here is to replace the default regex delimiter `/` by `:`, so that we can use '/' in our matching pattern.

**Final sotuion**:

```
sed -i '\:</tbody>: {
r /dev/stdin
a </tbody>
d}' ${inserttarget} < <(sed -n '\:<table>:,\:</table>:p' ${input} | sed -n '\:<tr>:p')
```

Et voila!

Comment: Thanks for updating; now it's `sed: can't read /\<tbody\>/,/\<\/tbody\>/p: No such file or directory` (Man, sed commands are ridiculously tough for a layman to parse.)

Comment: The command 'worked', but inputtarget.html ended up as an empty file. No errors, but no output, either. :)

Comment: You need to copy all four lines and paste them in your shell, because the `r` command has to be alone on the line, and I think that `a` needs that too.

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting ${inserttarget} outputted to stdin, but not actually edited. Have to poke at this some more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to put the `-i` back, now it should edit your file too! Sorry about that!

Comment: I can see the `</tbody>` move in the output, but the input `<tr>`'s aren't getting added. Maybe because there's no `<tbody>` in the input file, if I read the code right?

Comment: You are completely right, I replaced the `\:<tbody>:,\:</tbody>:` with `\:<table>:,\:</table>:`.

Comment: Still not getting the lines from input into the output for some reason. Feels close, though. I'll poke at the variables a bit and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Do you have any error message? because I just ran that without problem with command line.

Comment: Nope. No errors, and I can move the `</tbody>` over to see that it is reprinting that at least, because it moves. I'll prod it...

Comment: For the record, it's something in the round brackets, I think. If I replace `<(sed -n '\:<table>:,\:</table>:p' ${input} | sed -n '\:<tr>:p')` with `$input`, that inputs the full file in the right place, so there's something in the command that's not picking up my input. (Would the `<tr>` not being left justified do it?)

Comment: Aha. sed '\:<table>:,\:</table>:p' input.html gets me the whole file, not just the area between the tables. Getting closer.